What's the best YouTube Summary tool up to now? (2024-04-04)
What's the best YouTube Summary tool up to now? (2024-04-04) (in different aspects, summary accuracy, summary length, pricing, user-friendliness, etc.)
I have tried these tools:

Google Bard summarization. Prompt looks like @YouTube , summarize this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xm3wOOuMfrw
[MUNDANE] Elmo: Your WebCopilot. Elmo is powered by Lepton AI's blazing fast LLM APIs
Eightify: AI YouTube Summary with ChatGPT (NOT FREE, may need wait 10 hours to recharge)


Based on my personal experience, Eightify is the best.
Now(2024-12-02) I use YouTube Summary with ChatGPT & Claude
Any recommendation? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best in terms of what - summary accuracy, summary length, pricing? Regardless, I upvoted because it's an interesting topic

The Google offering is probably hard to beat, because Google owns Youtube, thus Google has has perfect access to Youtube content, and probably already has many AI workflows and products in place for analyzing their videos (right after uploading).
Also no 3rd party vendor can (theoretically, long-term) compete with Google on price (unless they burn money to get a user base first)
You should thus learn to use the multimodal Vertex AI APIs, owned by Google Cloud Platform. Tutorial example, sign-in required
Using such an API, in my opinion, enables you to  tweak and influence the summarization process yourself by setting certain "hyperparameters". There is for instance the "temperature" parameter which determines the "deterministicness" of the output (0 = always the same, 2 = gibberish).
Thus, that is some kind of creativity factor, for you to play with.
But there are others, e.g. "top_p", maximum length...
The webservices you have mentioned often just forward your input to some other AI service , and in doing so they set those parameters for you to make it easy.
